# SSH update to 14.04: The disk drive for / is not ready yet or not present

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2, upgrade, ssh

I am not able to restart my Ubuntu server after upgrade from 13 to 14.04. What can I do to make things work again?

I tried to upgrade my server over ssh to ubuntu 14.04. When the installation finished I saw the message “system restart required” so I did a “sudo reboot”. I was not able to reconnect via ssh afterwards. Well, I am able to access the server, so I had a look there.

After the reboot I have one rEFind and one Grub boot loader dialog, where I can choose Ubuntu. After doing this I get the message

```
“The disk drive for / is not ready yet or not present.
Continue to wait, or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery.”
```

However, nothing happens, when I press “S” or “M”.

I have got a Macintosh installation I can access on the machine, but was not able to mount the ubuntu device so far. There are many questions here and on Google on this topic, but most of them happen to use pressing "M". This is not possible for me, so therefore my question.

---

When I start Ubuntu in GRUB with advanced options, I can now start Ubuntu with the Linux 3.11.0-19-generic kernel. However, keyboard does function and therefore I understand now, why "M" or "S" options above are never activated.

---

While following tendons suggestion, it seems that I made a mistake and that at last the message above is still displayed. Here is what I did following this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109464/how-can-i-fix-install-reinstall-grub/109492#109492):

1. Created a KNOPPIX-Live USB stick and booted it (Mac users: 'C' for CD/DVD/USB)
2. Mounted the partition

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/foo
   ```
3. Bound the directories that grub needs to have access to

   ```
   sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/foo/dev  
   sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/foo/dev/pts 
   sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/foo/proc 
   sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/foo/sys
   ```
4. Set up the chroot environment

   ```
   sudo chroot /mnt/foo
   ```
5. Created grub's configuration file:

   ```
   sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
   ```
6. I have multiple operating systems installed and tried to make sure that the command above lists all of them (There were other messages like "image not found"):

   ```
   Generating grub.cfg ...
   Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
   Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-*-amd64
   ...
   done
   ```
7. Now I installed hopefully to the MBR of my drive with

   ```
   grub-install /dev/sda
   ```
8. Exited the chroot and unmounted everything.
9. `sudo umount /mnt/foo/dev/pts /mnt/foo/dev /mnt/foo/proc /mnt/foo/sys /mnt/foo`
10. <strike>When I rebooted, rEFInd was not able to start anymore. However, I came into grub again, but</strike>  It behaved like before...

---

Here is my grub.cfg - sda4 is the partition, where ubuntus / is. When I start KNOPPIX and want to access to the partition I have to mount /dev/sda4.

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt4'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=5
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea' {
recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt4'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=/dev/sda4 ro   quit splash processor.max_cstate=2 $vt_handoff
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-generic-advanced-1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=/dev/sda4 ro   quit splash processor.max_cstate=2 $vt_handoff
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-generic-recovery-1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=/dev/sda4 ro recovery nomodeset 
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-19-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-19-generic-advanced-1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.11.0-19-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-19-generic root=UUID=1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea ro   quit splash processor.max_cstate=2 $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-19-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-19-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-19-generic-recovery-1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.11.0-19-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-19-generic root=UUID=1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-19-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-18-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-18-generic-advanced-1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.11.0-18-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-18-generic root=UUID=1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea ro   quit splash processor.max_cstate=2 $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-18-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-18-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-18-generic-recovery-1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.11.0-18-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-18-generic root=UUID=1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-18-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-17-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-17-generic-advanced-1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.11.0-17-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-17-generic root=UUID=1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea ro   quit splash processor.max_cstate=2 $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-17-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-17-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-17-generic-recovery-1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.11.0-17-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-17-generic root=UUID=1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-17-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt4'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
    fi
    knetbsd /boot/memtest86+.elf
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt4'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1b12d4dd-8a3c-47b1-8b9d-7c6cbe5371ea
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Mac OS X (32-bit) (on /dev/sda2)' --class osx --class darwin --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-xnu-32-8a6a66edd559aa12'  {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod hfsplus
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  8a6a66edd559aa12
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8a6a66edd559aa12
    fi
        load_video
        set do_resume=0
        if [ /var/vm/sleepimage -nt10 / ]; then
           if xnu_resume /var/vm/sleepimage; then
             set do_resume=1
           fi
        fi
        if [ $do_resume = 0 ]; then
           xnu_uuid 8a6a66edd559aa12 uuid
           if [ -f /Extra/DSDT.aml ]; then
              acpi -e /Extra/DSDT.aml
           fi
           if [ /kernelcache -nt /System/Library/Extensions ]; then
              xnu_kernel /kernelcache boot-uuid=${uuid} rd=*uuid
           else
              xnu_kernel /mach_kernel boot-uuid=${uuid} rd=*uuid
              if [ /System/Library/Extensions.mkext -nt /System/Library/Extensions ]; then
                xnu_mkext /System/Library/Extensions.mkext
              else
                xnu_kextdir /System/Library/Extensions
              fi
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/Extensions.mkext ]; then
              xnu_mkext /Extra/Extensions.mkext
           fi
           if [ -d /Extra/Extensions ]; then
              xnu_kextdir /Extra/Extensions
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/devprop.bin ]; then
              xnu_devprop_load /Extra/devprop.bin
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/splash.jpg ]; then
              insmod jpeg
              xnu_splash /Extra/splash.jpg
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/splash.png ]; then
              insmod png
              xnu_splash /Extra/splash.png
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/splash.tga ]; then
              insmod tga
              xnu_splash /Extra/splash.tga
           fi
        fi
}
menuentry 'Mac OS X (64-bit) (on /dev/sda2)' --class osx --class darwin --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-xnu-64-8a6a66edd559aa12'  {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod hfsplus
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  8a6a66edd559aa12
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8a6a66edd559aa12
    fi
        load_video
        set do_resume=0
        if [ /var/vm/sleepimage -nt10 / ]; then
           if xnu_resume /var/vm/sleepimage; then
             set do_resume=1
           fi
        fi
        if [ $do_resume = 0 ]; then
           xnu_uuid 8a6a66edd559aa12 uuid
           if [ -f /Extra/DSDT.aml ]; then
              acpi -e /Extra/DSDT.aml
           fi
           if [ /kernelcache -nt /System/Library/Extensions ]; then
              xnu_kernel64 /kernelcache boot-uuid=${uuid} rd=*uuid
           else
              xnu_kernel64 /mach_kernel boot-uuid=${uuid} rd=*uuid
              if [ /System/Library/Extensions.mkext -nt /System/Library/Extensions ]; then
                xnu_mkext /System/Library/Extensions.mkext
              else
                xnu_kextdir /System/Library/Extensions
              fi
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/Extensions.mkext ]; then
              xnu_mkext /Extra/Extensions.mkext
           fi
           if [ -d /Extra/Extensions ]; then
              xnu_kextdir /Extra/Extensions
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/devprop.bin ]; then
              xnu_devprop_load /Extra/devprop.bin
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/splash.jpg ]; then
              insmod jpeg
              xnu_splash /Extra/splash.jpg
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/splash.png ]; then
              insmod png
              xnu_splash /Extra/splash.png
           fi
           if [ -f /Extra/splash.tga ]; then
              insmod tga
              xnu_splash /Extra/splash.tga
           fi
        fi
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

For me it seems fine...

Comment: Sounds like the disk identifiers were changed by the upgrade for some reason. Can you boot with a live CD and reinstall grub? See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109492/22222) for help on that.

Comment: This might be right, but I am not able to solve this issue that way. See my edit.

Comment: Strange. Could you post your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file? You can get it by booting the live session again and browsing your local drive. Find the menuentry for your Ubuntu and make sure the `set root=` line is pointing to the right drive.

Comment: @Stefan Bollmann Hey hi, I had a similar issue in a Ubuntu VM on my windows laptop and using a on screen keyboard solve it. You can not use  on screen keyboard if it's a physical server but you can try using some other keyboard type and it may work for you. However if it's a VM then OSK will help you. My issue was because of the sticky keys and this issue was only in that Ubuntu VM and not in my windows host OS. Hence it was a little tough at the beginning to find out this issue. :) give it a try :)